# How can i shuffle the gameobject list

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a Gem(cubes) that have sphere as the children. How can i shuffle these gems and sphere to change their position? I tried some snippet to shuffle their positions but I am getting errors. How can i shuffle these gems? Please help me to sort it out.

**Board.cs**

```
 public List<Gem> gems = new List<Gem>();
        public int GridWidth;
        public int GridHeight;
        public GameObject gemprefab;
        public Gem gemComponent;
        public Vector3[] shuffleArray = new Vector3[gems.Count];
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {

            ChangePosition();
        }
        public void ChangePosition() {

        for (int i = 0; i < shuffleArray.Length; i++) {
            int temp = gems[i].transform.position;
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, shuffleArray.Length);
            gems[i].transform.position = gems[randomIndex];
            gems[randomIndex] = temp;


            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
for(int i = 0; i < gems.Count; i++) {
    Vector3 temp = gems[i].transform.position;
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, gems.Count);
    gems[i].transform.position = gems[randomIndex].transform.position;
    gems[randomIndex].transform.position = temp;
}
```